# VNA based calibration of RF equipment relative to discreet time domain measurments

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

I am looking for methodology on how to correct data for losses present in RF signal paths.

The basis for my objective is to convert an discreet time domain signal into the frequency domain with an FFT, fold S-parameter info from a network analyzer into the FFT data, then IFFT the new corrected data back to the time domain.

The purpose here is pretty basic, for example: a 6dB attenuator ideally has a factor of 2 response, I could just multiply my measured voltages by 2 and move on.

But naturally nothing is perfect. That same 6dB attenuator coyld be measured to have a 6db loss at 100khz and a 7dB loss at 1ghz, etc. Thus by using the network analyzer to measure the actual loss across the frequency band you can correct for the variation in the component.

Obviously I know for the most part what I need to do, what I'm having a hard time finding is any kind of guide on this process. I'm certian there are instructional documents to that exist. As this seems like something scientists would do often to ensure quality meaaured data.

But I must be missing a key word or something when I go looking, as I find lots of info about calibrating network analyzers, but very little about using the analyzers results to process losses out of time domain signal.

Any help to point me in the right direction is appreciated.
Or, if some one had a PDF or paper they could share, even better.